# Appending multiple values to a Cookie

Tags: c#, cookies

I am trying to store a few values in one cookie rather than creating a lot of cookies. I have a functions to get a named value and set the values for given names.

When the form is reloaded the cookie seems to be empty...And on at least 1 occasion there seemed to be 2 cookies with the same name in the collection.

The code is below, can anyone see what I have done wrong?

To clarify there is one cookie, which should store several values which would be called with code similar to below

```
        CookieValues.Set("Test", "TheTestValue", resp);
        CookieValues.Set("Name", "Nick", resp);
        CookieValues.Set("Sex", "male", resp);
        var x = CookieValues.Get("Test", resp);    


public static class CookieValues
{

    public static void Set(string key, string value, HttpResponseBase resp)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = GetCookie(resp);

        cookie[key] = value;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        resp.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    public static string Get(string key, HttpResponseBase resp)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = GetCookie(resp);

        if (cookie[key] != null)
        {
            return cookie[key];
        }

        return "";
    }

    private static HttpCookie GetCookie(HttpResponseBase resp)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = resp.Cookies["HolidayAdmin"];
        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("HolidayAdmin");
        }
        return cookie;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does `I am trying to store a few values in one cookie` fit in your code? As far as I can tell your code only applies to 1 cookie.

Comment: And how do you call this code? With what values?

Comment: I have updated the question, to answer your comments. Sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a licensed guru on cookies in c# so I fear I might be missing something, but this is my interpretation of the issue anyway.

You're adding and getting cookies from the *response*. So they should be available right after creation (within the same response). But once the response is gone, and the cookie is actually set on the client, you'd have to get it by using *request* (or so I believe).

One way then, would be to just change your `Get` method to:

```
public static string Get(string key, HttpRequestBase resp)
```

And, obviously, send the request this way. This should mean that you can only request the cookie after it has actually been set on the client - i.e. on a new request. But it seems that the response actually copies this to the request right on creation, so it should be available even within the current *response*.

If it's not though, it might be an idea to check both the response and request in your `Get`.

Comment: I change the code to use the response and it seems to be working now. I'll post the code after I have done more testing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the continued adding of the cookie to the response in your `Set` method:

```
resp.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

If you create three cookie values now, you have three cookies since you add them three times.

I would recommend to adjust the `GetCookie(HttpResponse)` method to also add the cookie. You could remove the call from `Set` then.

```
private static HttpCookie GetCookie(HttpResponseBase resp)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = resp.Cookies["HolidayAdmin"];
    if (cookie == null)
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("HolidayAdmin");
        resp.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
    return cookie;
}
```

Comment: Not sure I follow "_[...] since you add them three times._". Shouldn't `if (cookie == null)` make sure it's only added once (assuming _Cookies[key]_ actually returns null if it doesn't exist)? Ahh, never mind - it's never actually added to the response, or I assume it doesn't have time to get added before the next `Set` is called..

Comment: @Mackan: You are right. I updated the first line to make clear where the error is in.

Comment: @Nick: need more help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to execute this code, from what i see you are trying to create a cookie "HolidayAdmin" and the value for this cookie is being set as key value pairs.

```
"HolidayAdmin" -- Test=ThetestValue&name=nick&Sex=male
```

Comment: That's how cookies are stored. The question is why he can't retrieve them after a page reload, and why there is sometimes duplicate cookies.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be working for me now. Main differences are using request and response now. Also where the cookie is persisted

```
public static class CookieValues
{
    public static void test(HttpResponseBase resp, HttpRequestBase request, HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        Set("Test", "123", request, response);
        Set("Name", "Nick", request, response);
        Set("Sex", "male", request, response);
        var x = Get("Test", request);
    }


    public static void Set(string key, string value, HttpRequestBase request, HttpResponseBase response)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = GetCookie(request);

        cookie[key] = value;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }


    public static string Get(string key, HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = GetCookie(request);

        if (cookie[key] != null)
        {
            return cookie[key];
        }

        return "";
    }

    private static HttpCookie GetCookie(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = request.Cookies["HolidayAdmin"];

        if (cookie == null)
        {
            cookie = new HttpCookie("HolidayAdmin");
            request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        return cookie;
    }
}
```